# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed. Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web-config, connection-pooling

, it was working fine I have no clue about this error what should I do

Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

```
Stack Trace: 

[ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) +301
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.GetDbProviderFactorySecure() +48
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.CreateConnection(String connectionString) +14
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +208
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +186
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +51
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +16
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3888
```

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same problem why trying to publish a website to a new server.  Installing the Connector/Net 6.4.4 found here solved my problem: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/